.dll Targeting 'AMD64' Incompatible with x86 Project (Tried Common Solutions)
I'm encountering the error ".dll targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'" while building my project in Visual Studio 2019. I've already tried the following solutions but haven't been successful:

Switched project target platform to x64.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project thoroughly.

Here's some additional information that might be helpful:
Project type: Wpf C#
IDE version: 2019
Operating System: windows 11
Has anyone else faced this issue?
